# Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting error when I execute my code. Below code used for creating collection in cloud Firestore, before this I didn’t created any collection in cloud Firestore. It is empty. In the console.log, I am getting correct json object.

```
 createEntry(subjectId: string, questionnaire: string, callback: (err: any, response: any) => void) :void {
    let testEntity: TestEntity = new TestEntity(subjectId, questionnaire);
    console.log("testEntity.toJSON();----------->",testEntity.toJSON());
    var docRef = this.dbManager.collection('testQuestion').doc(subjectId);
var setAlan = docRef.set(testEntity.toJSON());
}
```

Here TestEntity is json values as below. All the fields have values.

```
public toJSON(): testEntry {
    let returnJSON = {
        "entry_id": this.entry_id,
        "subject_id": this.subject_id,
        "entry_date": this.entry_date,
        "questionnaire": this.questionnaire,
        "entry_start_timestamp": this.entry_start_timestamp,
        "entry_end_timestamp": this.entry_end_timestamp,
        "entry_complete": this.entry_complete,
        "responses": this.responses,
        "last_answered_question" : this.last_answered_question,
        "entry_status" : this.entry_status
    }

    return returnJSON;
}
```

dbManager is this.adminInstance:

```
export class DatabaseManager{
    private static adminInstance:any;

    static getAdminInstance(): any {
    if(!this.adminInstance)
        admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    this.adminInstance   =   admin;
    return this.adminInstance.firestore();
    }
}
```

I am getting below error. How to solve it?

```
Error: Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument.

   at Object.exports.customObjectError.val [as customObjectError] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:164:14)
    at Function.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:813:20)
    at Function.encodeFields (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:683:36)
    at Function.fromObject (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:223:55)
    at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:301:39)
    at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:420:8)
    at testEntryService.createEntry (/user_code/services/test-entry-service.js:19:30)
    at /user_code/services/intentService.js:22:36
    at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:146:23)
    at next (native)
```

Since I am new to Firebase, I am unable to identify this error. What is the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase firestore cloud functions showing Error: Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112925/firebase-firestore-cloud-functions-showing-error-invalid-use-of-type-undefined)

Comment: Have a look at the following QO questiona & answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112925/firebase-firestore-cloud-functions-showing-error-invalid-use-of-type-undefined

Comment: Could you edit the question to show exactly the value you're trying to put into the document in the call to set()?

Comment: let setAlan = docRef.set({
            'entry_id': '7cf93279-de0f-497d-a789-0ae12804c19c',
            'subject_id': subject',
            'entry_date': '2018-06-15',
            'questionnaire': 1,
            'entry_start_timestamp': '2018-06-15T11:38:57.030Z',
            'entry_end_timestamp': '2018-06-15T11:38:57.030Z',
            'entry_complete': false,
            'last_answered_question': 0,
            'entry_status': 'active'

        });